# Regex : conditions in captured variables

Tags: regex, perl, expression, conditional-statements

This is my data (in a file):

```
5807035;Fab;2015/01/05;04;668100;18:06:01,488;18:06:02,892
5807028;Opt;2015/01/05;04;836100;17:12:45,223;17:12:47,407
5807028;Fab;2015/01/05;04;836100;17:12:47,470;17:12:48,172
5807027;Opt;2015/01/05;04;926100;17:12:31,807;17:12:34,365
5807027;Fab;2015/01/05;04;926100;17:12:34,443;17:12:37,095
5807026;Opt;2015/01/05;04;682100;17:12:11,698;17:12:19,062
5807026;Fab;2015/01/05;04;682100;17:12:19,124;17:12:21,667
5807025;Opt;2015/01/05;04;217100;17:12:00,669;17:12:02,635
```

This is my `Perl` code :

```
while ( $data =~ m/(\d+);(Opt|Fab);(.+);(\d{2});(.+);(.+);(.+)\n(\d+);(Opt|Fab);.+;\d{2};.+;(.+);(.+)\n/g ) { 

    if ( "$1" eq "$8" && "$2" ne "$9" ) {
        print OUTFILE "$1;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7;$10;$11\n";
    }
}
```

The lines 1 and 2 match the regex, but do not satisfy the condition of the `if` statement. That's fine.

On the other hand, the lines 2 and 3 satisfy the regex, AND the condition of the `if` statement. However, it these lines are not retrieved.

I suppose it's because the regex read two lines, then the next two lines, etc. I think I should include the condition of the `if` statement in the regex (if I'm not mistaken).

What do you guys think ?

The variable `$data` holds the content of my CSV file.

Comment: Whenever you're working with delimited data, I would recommend using `split` (or [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) if fields can contain the delimiter) and assigning meaningful variable names to the columns. Maintaining code with enormous regexes and variables `$1` through `$11` is very difficult and error prone.

Comment: There is only one column (col 2) in your csv data that contains `Opt|Fab`, therefore the regex can never match any of the lines, since field 9 should also be `Opt|Fab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to check line 1 & 2, then 2 & 3, you need to prevent the regex engine from consuming the 2nd line by placing the regex to match the second line in a look-ahead:

```
while ( $data =~ m/(\d+);(Opt|Fab);(.+);(\d{2});(.+);(.+);(.+)\n(?=(\d+);(Opt|Fab);.+;\d{2};.+;(.+);(.+)\n)/g ) {
```

I didn't think too much when I first answer, but as @ThisSuitIsBlackNot suggested in the comment, using regular expression to parse CSV results in low maintainability code. Using CSV library to parse the data and process them is a better idea here.